google chrome in ubuntu studio 24.04
cannot install google chrome in Ubuntu studio 24.04 - it says that dependencies are not met? can anyone help? i tried downloading from google website an to install via packed manager.

does this Ubuntu Handbook article help

This question is similar to: How to let `dpkg -i` install dependencies for me?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

sorry to complex for me....
